# htaccess redirect wildcard with encoding

Tags: regex, redirect, wildcard, utf

We migrated a site that had UTF urls to Apache, example:

[http://domain.com/décor](http://domain.com/d%C3%A9cor)

On the new site, it winds up in a 404. I tried a wildcard:

```
/d(.*)cor
```

But that still results in a 404. In looking at the network request in Chrome Developer tools, the actual URL requested was:

```
/d%C3%A9cor
```

Is there a means to still include a wildcard for the encoded characters that WILL work? We have a ton of é in URLs and I'd like to just create a wildcard rule to properly redirect all so any é is replaced with e.

Comment: `d(.*)cor` matches `d%C3%A9cor` we'll need more information